# Change Android App Theme Permanently

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I am making an app in Android Studio. I want to make the app full screen. I would change the theme using the button in the application, but if I change the phone or refresh the app, it would change back. Please help!

Comment: Please add your code whatever you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're trying 'Design preview in Android studio'.
In 'Design' tab (where you're in right now), you can just see how it would look like in different phones and Android SDK versions.

If you want to change the App theme permanently,

1. Go to `res/values/styles.xml` and custom your own theme   -ex) 'AppTheme'
2. In `AndroidManifest.xml`, you can set it via namespace 'theme' like this `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"`

Comment: But how would I make a theme that makes the app full screen. I don't know how to make a custom theme

Comment: Well.. you should learn how to do it by searching 'android custom theme'
When you look into `styles.xml`, you'll see your current theme extending something like `"Theme.AppCompat.Light"`.

There are so many different themes you can choose like `"Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"`.

Comment: If you want to hide statusBar also, you need some coding in your activity.
Search with `setSystemUiVisibility`.